# Certificate pinning for device firmware signing

Tags: code-signing, certificate-pinning

What are common mechanisms to ensure that a device firmware is not only properly signed, but actually signed by the correct device manufacturer? In TLS communications, certificate pinning or public key pinning is used. But if I want to use a device configuration tool (Windows-based) to update a device firmware and want to ensure that the device firmware is not only signed, but actually signed by me as the device manufacturer, is there anything similar?

We've looked at using the Subject string in the code signing certificate, but recently CA Browser Forum rule changes forces us to change the string there. Also, pinning an intermediate CA won't work, since recent rule changes in our code signing certificate provider changed our CA hierarchy and we can't rely on that to be static (enough) for devices with several years if not decades of lifetime in the field. Public key pinning is likely not going to work since the keys of the code signing certificates typically change every time we renew the code signing certificate.